# How to give more weightage for one attributes in DSL query search string

Tags: python, elasticsearch, dsl

Below is the sample data in elasticsearch

```
   PUT /data/test/1
 {
       "id": "Accounting 101",
       "room": "E3",
       "professor": {
           "name": "Thomas Baszo",
           "email": "baszot@onuni.com"
           },
       "students_enrolled": 27,
       "course_description": " financial statements"
   }
   
   PUT /data/test/2
   {
       "name": "Accounting 101",
       "room": "E3",
       "professor": {
           "name": "Sachin Baszo",
           "email": "baszot@onuni.com"
           },
       "students_enrolled": 27, 
       "course_description": "Thomas  Thomas Thomas Thomas "
   }
```

Below is the query

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "(*Thomas*)"
    }
  }
}
```

My output will show second document as first as it contains "Thomas" 4 times in the description

- I need to give more weightage to `professor.name` it should show first check if not then check "professor.email" then check other attributes

Python

`es.search(index="data", body={"query": {"query_string": {"query": "(*Thomas*)"}}})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not recommended to use `query_string`, as mentioned in the [ES official documentation:](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html)

> Because it returns an error for any invalid syntax, we don’t recommend
> using the query_string query for search boxes.
>
> If you don’t need to support a query syntax, consider using the match
> query. If you need the features of a query syntax, use the
> simple_query_string query, which is less strict.

You can use [Boost](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-boost.html) where

> Individual fields can be boosted automatically — count more towards
> the relevance score — at query time

Adding a working example with index mapping, search query, and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "professor": {
                "properties": {
                    "name": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "boost": 2
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
 {
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query": "Thomas", 
      "fields": [ "course_description", "professor.name" ] 
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
            {
                "_index": "stof_63933144",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 1.3862942,     <-- note this
                "_source": {
                    "id": "Accounting 101",
                    "room": "E3",
                    "professor": {
                        "name": "Thomas Baszo",
                        "email": "baszot@onuni.com"
                    },
                    "students_enrolled": 27,
                    "course_description": " financial statements"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "stof_63933144",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 1.1090355,   <-- note this
                "_source": {
                    "name": "Accounting 101",
                    "room": "E3",
                    "professor": {
                        "name": "Sachin Baszo",
                        "email": "baszot@onuni.com"
                    },
                    "students_enrolled": 27,
                    "course_description": "Thomas  Thomas Thomas Thomas "
                }
            }
        ]
```

**Update 1:**

Search query for searching for `Thomas` OR `Sachin`

```
 {
      "query": {
        "multi_match" : {
          "query": "(Thomas) OR (Sachin)", 
          "fields": [ "course_description", "professor.name" ] 
        }
      }
    }
```

**Update 2:**

Multi match query using `"operator":"OR"`

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query": "Thomas Sachin", 
      "fields": [ "course_description", "professor.name" ] ,
      "operator":"OR",
      "type":"cross_fields"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bhavya, if i want to search  for Thomas and Sachin  `{"query": {"query_string": {"query": "(*Thomas* OR *Sachin*)"}}})` how to add that?

Comment: without changing the `query` term can we do that

Comment: @Nons please go through my updated answer, and let me know if the above search query worked for you or not ?

Comment: @Nons glad I could be of your help :) Thank u for accepting the answer, it would be great if you can upvote this as well :)

Comment: Okay, @Nons Thank you :)

Comment: last question, is there any way to give hierarchy to check the attributes.  first check "professor.name", "professor.email" "course description"

Comment: @BhavyaGupta: I believe ""query": "(Thomas) OR (Sachin)"" is not the correct syntax with muti_match query. It will match documents with "OR". Instead use "operator":"or"

Comment: @SahilGupta thanks for pointing this out :) I have added the update of the search query with `"operator":"OR"` as well. But, I find that there is not much difference in the score when compared to the previous search query (i.e without explicitly mentioning `"operator":"OR"`). And if you liked the answer, please don't forget to upvote the answer as well :)

Comment: @Nons I think this might be possible by using bool queries, but it will be entirely a different approach. It would be better if you post another question, with your new requirements.
Please ping me when you post the new question, and I will definitely try to answer that :)

Comment: Thanks @Nons , I will go through this

Comment: @Nons added my answer, please go through this https://stackoverflow.com/a/63937212/10348758