# How to add weightage in DSL query with hierarchy of attributes

Tags: python, elasticsearch, dsl

- I need to search more weightage to `professor.name`
- Then next attribute to get the weightage is `professor.email`
- The check the other fields where search string is there

Below is the sample data in elasticsearch

```
   PUT /data/test/1
 {
       "id": "Accounting 101",
       "room": "E3",
       "professor": {
           "name": "Thomas Baszo",
           "email": "baszot@onuni.com"
           },
       "students_enrolled": 27,
       "course_description": " financial statements"
   }
   
   PUT /data/test/2
   {
       "name": "Accounting 101",
       "room": "E3",
       "professor": {
           "name": "Sachin Baszo",
           "email": "baszot@onuni.com"
           },
       "students_enrolled": 27, 
       "course_description": "Thomas  Thomas Thomas Thomas "
   }

   PUT /data/test/3
   {
       "name": "Accounting 101",
       "room": "E3",
       "professor": {
           "name": "Sachin Baszo",
           "email": "Thomas@onuni.com"
           },
       "students_enrolled": 27, 
       "course_description": "Nothing"
   }
```

Below is the query

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "(*Thomas*)"
    }
  }
}
```

My output will show second document as first as it contains "Thomas" 4 times in the description

- I need to give more weightage to `professor.name` it should show first check if not then check "professor.email" then check other attributes

Expected out is `1,3,2` 1 because name, 3 because of email and 2 because of description

Python

`es.search(index="data", body={"query": {"query_string": {"query": "(*Thomas*)"}}})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a working example with index data, search query, and search result

The [boost](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-boost.html#mapping-boost) can be applied to the individual fields as well while creating the index as explained in the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63933646/10348758)

**Index Data:**

```
{
    "id": "Accounting 101",
    "room": "E3",
    "professor": {
        "name": "Thomas Baszo",
        "email": "baszot@onuni.com"
    },
    "students_enrolled": 27,
    "course_description": " financial statements"
}
{
    "name": "Accounting 101",
    "room": "E3",
    "professor": {
        "name": "Sachin Baszo",
        "email": "baszot@onuni.com"
    },
    "students_enrolled": 27,
    "course_description": "Thomas  Thomas Thomas Thomas "
}
{
    "name": "Accounting 101",
    "room": "E3",
    "professor": {
        "name": "Baszo",
        "email": "Thomas@onuni.com"
    },
    "students_enrolled": 27,
    "course_description": "Nothing"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "multi_match": {
          "query": "Thomas",
          "fields": [
            "professor.name^16",
            "professor.email^8",
            "course_description^4"
          ]
        }
      },
      "boost_mode": "multiply"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "stof_63933144",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 14.506382,
        "_source": {
          "id": "Accounting 101",
          "room": "E3",
          "professor": {
            "name": "Thomas Baszo",
            "email": "baszot@onuni.com"
          },
          "students_enrolled": 27,
          "course_description": " financial statements"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "stof_63933144",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 7.846633,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Accounting 101",
          "room": "E3",
          "professor": {
            "name": "Baszo",
            "email": "Thomas@onuni.com"
          },
          "students_enrolled": 27,
          "course_description": "Nothing"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "stof_63933144",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 5.9089565,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Accounting 101",
          "room": "E3",
          "professor": {
            "name": "Sachin Baszo",
            "email": "baszot@onuni.com"
          },
          "students_enrolled": 27,
          "course_description": "Thomas  Thomas Thomas Thomas "
        }
      }
    ]
```

**Update 1:**

To search for bor both `Thomas OR Sachin`, you can use the below query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "multi_match": {
          "query": "Thomas Sachin",
          "fields": [
            "professor.name^16",
            "professor.email^8",
            "course_description^4"
          ],
          "operator": "OR",
          "type": "cross_fields"
        }
      },
      "boost_mode": "multiply"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Nons let me know if this was the expected result which you want ?

Comment: can i add `"query": "(Thomas OR Sachin)", ` to search multiple string ?

Comment: @Nons please go through my updated answer, and let me know if this resolved your query ?

Comment: How to do above in query in `match all`  condition

Comment: @Nons I have added my answer, to your other question, please go through this https://stackoverflow.com/a/64275429/10348758