# How to boost the field in match_all elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl

- I need to search more weightage to professor.name
- Then next attribute to get the weightage is professor.email
- The check the other fields where search string is there
  Below is the sample data in elasticsearch

  ```
   PUT /data/test/1
  {
       "id": "Accounting 101",
       "room": "E3",
       "professor": {
           "name": "Thomas Baszo",
           "email": "baszot@onuni.com"
           },
       "students_enrolled": 27,
       "course_description": " financial statements"
   }

   PUT /data/test/2
   {
       "name": "Accounting 101",
       "room": "E3",
       "professor": {
           "name": "Sachin Baszo",
           "email": "baszot@onuni.com"
           },
       "students_enrolled": 27, 
       "course_description": "Thomas  Thomas Thomas Thomas "
   }

   PUT /data/test/3
   {
       "name": "Accounting 101",
       "room": "E3",
       "professor": {
           "name": "Sachin Baszo",
           "email": "Thomas@onuni.com"
           },
       "students_enrolled": 27, 
       "course_description": "Nothing"
   }
  ```

Below is the query

GET /_search

`{"from" : 0, "size" : 100,"query": {"match_all": {}}})`

How to implement `"fields": [ "professor.name^16", "professor.email^8"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [multi_match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html) build on the match query to allow multi-field queries:

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query" : "thomas",
      "fields" : [ "professor.name^16", "professor.email^8"]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "stof_64275333",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 15.693266,
        "_source": {
          "id": "Accounting 101",
          "room": "E3",
          "professor": {
            "name": "Thomas Baszo",
            "email": "baszot@onuni.com"
          },
          "students_enrolled": 27,
          "course_description": " financial statements"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "stof_64275333",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 7.846633,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Accounting 101",
          "room": "E3",
          "professor": {
            "name": "Sachin Baszo",
            "email": "Thomas@onuni.com"
          },
          "students_enrolled": 27,
          "course_description": "Nothing"
        }
      }
    ]
```